# Python: How to copy elements from list that start with a certain letter into new list or remove elements from list that do not start with letter

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables, element

I am getting a list from an excel file using pandas.

```
start_path = r'C:\scratch\\'
File = 'test.xlsx'
import pandas as pd 
mylist = []
df = pd.read_excel(start_path + File, sheet_name='GIS')
mylist = df['Column A'].tolist()
```

List:

```
mylist = ['LB-52/LP-7', 'LB-53/LI-5', 'LB-54/LP-8', 'LB-55', 'LB-56', 'ABC']
```

My goal is to then create a new list from this list, only with the elements that start with LB. So the new list would then be:

```
newlist = ['LB-52/LP-7', 'LB-53/LI-5', 'LB-54/LP-8', 'LB-55', 'LB-56']
```

Or just remove all elements from a list that do not start with 'LB' (thus removing ABC from the list).

```
newlist = [str(x for x in mylist if "LB" in x)]
```

I tried the above and this just spits out:

```
['<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000024B5B8F62C8>']
```

I also have tried the following:

```
approved = ['LB']
mylist[:] = [str(x for x in mylist if any(sub in x for sub in approved))]
```

This gets the same generator object message as before.

I feel like this is really simple but cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.startswith` in list-comprehension:

```py
mylist = ["LB-52/LP-7", "LB-53/LI-5", "LB-54/LP-8", "LB-55", "LB-56", "ABC"]

newlist = [value for value in mylist if value.startswith("LB")]
print(newlist)
```

Prints:

```
['LB-52/LP-7', 'LB-53/LI-5', 'LB-54/LP-8', 'LB-55', 'LB-56']
```

---

You can remove `str()` in `newlist = [str(x for x in mylist if "LB" in x)]` but this will leave values such as `xxxLBxxx` (`LB` is inside the string)

Answer (score 1):

```
newlist = [x for x in mylist if x[0:2]=="LB"]
```

You can also use slicing and also check on desired indices with slicing

Answer (score 0):

In general, pandas tends to do the same job faster than python. Therefore you should try to do most of your computation or filtering in pandas before "moving over" to python.

```py
mylist = df.loc[df['Column A'].str.startswith("LB"), 'Column A'].tolist()
mylist
>>> ['LB-52/LP-7', 'LB-53/LI-5', 'LB-54/LP-8', 'LB-55', 'LB-56']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
mylist = ['LB-52/LP-7', 'LB-53/LI-5', 'LB-54/LP-8', 'LB-55', 'LB-56', 'ABC']
new_list = [*filter(lambda x: x.startswith('LB'), mylist)]
# ['LB-52/LP-7', 'LB-53/LI-5', 'LB-54/LP-8', 'LB-55', 'LB-56']
```

Answer (score -1):

This code works

```
newlist = ['LB-52/LP-7', 'LB-53/LI-5', 'LB-54/LP-8', 'LB-55', 'LB-56']
mylist=   [ch for ch in newlist if ch[0:2]=="LB"]
```

Comment: This answer is already present?